# How to add element from user in numpy matrix from user for nxn matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

```
from numpy import matrix

new = matrix([raw_input("enter element in matrix. . ")]) # add element from user
```

take row and col size from user and like in c matrix how to enter nxn matrix using numpy

```
matrix([for i in row: for j in col: raw_input(add >data)])
```

Comment: What format would the user response be in?  The `raw_input` only prompts for an element, not a row or column number.

Comment: user will enter like 3 row and 3 col

Comment: So will the user enter just the size of the matrix, (like `(3,3)` in your example) not the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to the other answer, I would use `ast.literal_eval` instead of the built-in `eval` as it is *much* safer. If you want you can have the user input `(n,m)` the matrix dimension ahead of time. It is also a good idea to check that the number of elements matches what you expect! An example of all this:

```
import numpy as np
import ast

# Example input for a 3x2 matrix of numbers
n,m = 3,2
s = raw_input("Enter space sep. matrix elements: ")

# Use literal_eval
items  = map(ast.literal_eval, s.split(' '))

# Check to see if it matches
assert(len(items) == n*m)

# Convert to numpy array and reshape to the right size
matrix = np.array(items).reshape((n,m))

print matrix
```

Example output:

```
Enter space sep. matrix elements: 1 2 3 4 5 6
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks Hookes.it is good example .Thanks.

Comment: @Dhairya I'm glad the answer helped and welcome to Stack Overflow! If you feel this completes your question please "accept" this answer by clicking on the green check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval to evaluate the string given by the user into a Python object.  If you provide the 3x3 matrix in list format, matrix can take it from there.

BE CAREFUL.  The use of eval in code can let people provide malicious commands.  If this is going into production code, it's probably not a good idea.

```
>>> new = matrix([eval(raw_input("enter matrix: "))])
enter matrix: [1,2]
>>> new
matrix([[1, 2]])
```